# regexp_replace replacing one list with another list SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I replace the 3 letter strings in each of these columns with a corresponding single character string.

```
    ('Ala' = 'A','Arg' = 'R','Glu' = 'E', 'Lys' = 'K', 'Ser' = 'S', 'Thr' = 'T', 'Ile' = 'I', 'Leu' = 'L', 'Met' = 'M')
```

| Column A |
| --- |
| Arg790Met |
| Gly724Ser |
| Leu858Arg |
| Lys768Ile |
| Thr790Met |
| Glu746Ala750del |

So I end up with:

| Column A |
| --- |
| R790M |
| G724S |
| L858R |
| k768I |
| T790M |
| E746A750del |

Unfortunately it isn't as simple as taking first letter as not all have first letter as the short code.

I have tried `regexp_replace` but can't work out how to replace with list. I can't separate out the different parts of the main string replace them then recombine as they might be longer than 11 charters and there are some 3 character elements I want to leave untouched like 'del'.

There is the option to do nested `regexp_replace` functions but my full list is 21 long so this would look awful and I wondered if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this in Oracle, sans a custom UDF of some kind.

Comment: I agree, a PL/SQL function would be the best option. As of Oracle 12c this can even be part of the query (`WITH FUNCTION ... SELECT ...`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a recursive query and simple string functions to recurse through the sub-strings and, in turn, replace each three-character code with its abbreviation, if it exists:

```sql
WITH replacements (columna, spos) AS (
  SELECT columna, 1 FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(columna, 1, spos - 1)
         || COALESCE(t.abbr, SUBSTR(columna, spos, 3))
         || SUBSTR(columna, spos + 3),
         spos + NVL2(t.code, LENGTH(t.abbr), 3) + 3
  FROM   replacements r
         LEFT OUTER JOIN translations t
         ON SUBSTR(columna, spos, 3) = t.code
  WHERE  spos < LENGTH(columna)
)
  SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY columna SET order_id
SELECT columna
FROM   replacements
WHERE  spos >= LENGTH(columna);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE translations (code, abbr) AS
SELECT 'Ala', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Arg', 'R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Glu', 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lys', 'K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ser', 'S' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Thr', 'T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ile', 'I' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Leu', 'L' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Met', 'M' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_name (ColumnA) AS
SELECT 'Arg790Met' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gly724Ser' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Leu858Arg' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lys768Ile' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Thr790Met' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Glu746Ala750del' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COLUMNA |
| --- |
| R790M |
| E746A750del |
| Gly724S |
| L858R |
| K768I |
| T790M |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zb3-WkPz)

---

If you can have variable length numeric separators then you can use `REGEXP_INSTR` to find the end of each number:

```sql
WITH replacements (columna, spos) AS (
  SELECT columna, 1 FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(columna, 1, spos - 1)
         || COALESCE(t.abbr, SUBSTR(columna, spos, 3))
         || SUBSTR(columna, spos + 3),
         REGEXP_INSTR(
           columna,
           '\d*',
           spos + 3,
           1,
           1
         ) - NVL2(t.code, 3 - LENGTH(t.abbr), 0)
  FROM   replacements r
         LEFT OUTER JOIN translations t
         ON SUBSTR(columna, spos, 3) = t.code
  WHERE  spos > 0
)
  SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY columna SET order_id
SELECT columna
FROM   replacements
WHERE  spos <= 0
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE translations (code, abbr) AS
SELECT 'Ala', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Arg', 'R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Glu', 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lys', 'K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ser', 'S' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Thr', 'T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ile', 'I' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Leu', 'L' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Met', 'M' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_name (ColumnA) AS
SELECT 'Arg790Met' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gly724Ser' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Leu858Arg' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lys768Ile' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Thr790Met' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Glu746Ala750del' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lys1768Ile' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lys68Ile' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COLUMNA |
| --- |
| R790M |
| E746A750del |
| Gly724S |
| L858R |
| K1768I |
| K68I |
| K768I |
| T790M |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ieMNR6MR)

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for unknown number of digits between the strings of interest? i.e. so it could cope with 'Lys1768Ile' or 'Lys68Ile'